# Can 自身 be used to refer to 2 people in the same sentence?

Tags: usage, syntax, suffixes, word-usage, reflexives

Starting from the sentence:

> それにもかかわらず、新渡戸と内村は女性の状況や権利に特別な関心を抱き、これについての文書を多数残している。

Do I need to add 2「自身」to give the meaning "Nitobe and Uchimura themselves"?

> それにもかかわらず、新渡戸**自身**と内村**自身**は女性の状況や権利に特別な関心を抱き、これについての文書を多数残している。

Can I accomplish the meaning of "themselves" with only 1「自身」in the sentence after the second name be able to **refer to both** of them?

> 「新渡戸と内村**自身**は」

="Nitobe and Uchimura themselves"?

or will that merely mean

"Nitobe, and Uchimura himself"?

Comment: Thank you for these clarifying edits, virmaior and snailboat!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest and surest way to do it that would leave no room for misunderstanding (and maintain at least the fine newspaper article quality) would be to say:

> 「新渡戸、内村（の）[両氏自身]{りょうしじしん}」 or
>
> 「新渡戸・内村両氏自身」 or
>
> 「新渡戸[及]{およ}び内村（の）両氏自身」

「両氏」 can be replaced by 「[両名]{りょうめい}」 without changing any nuance.

Comment: @seijitsu 氏 is like "Mr.", and I assume you're writing some objective article where 氏 after 新渡戸/内村 is rather undesirable. If that's the case, don't suddenly add 両氏 after their names, either. 「新渡戸・内村の両名自身」 would be OK, but I personally think simple 「新渡戸と内村自身」 is enough .